# How do I change file permissions on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, file-permissions

How can I programmatically change a file's permission to be writable?

The input are read-only files, and I want to know if there is a general a way to guarantee that I can turn on writability/turn off read-only, no matter what version of Windows (XP, server-2003, or higher).

Comment: Here is the method - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-chmod

Comment: ahh, I didn't realize that I could pass the characters instead of just the bitmaps...

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow wants you to show the things you've tried, so we know what not to duplicate. It also helps as we can correct your mistake, instead of write something that is unrelated to your previous work, which you then have to shoehorn into shape.

Answer (score 2):

The read-only attibute in Windows is set with the [attrib command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATTRIB).

```
exec "attrib +R 12345.jpg" #sets the read-only file attribute
exec "attrib -R 12345.jpg" #removes the read-only file attribute
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FileUtils.chmod 'a+x', %w(foo.txt bar.txt)
```

That is based off of @Arup's comment of using http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-chmod  -- which works for me, and it stays in pure ruby.

Comment: You could also write the actual code in your answer, so that others can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way. Install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) on your windows system
Then access your folder using

```
cd /cygdrive/c/
```

Then use [chmod](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions) for changing permissions.